# How to send json to web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to submit json from a controller in an MVC app to a Web API app.

In the Web API app, one of the controller methods takes a string:

```
//In ValuesController.cs
[HttpGet("{myjson}")]
public string Index (string myjson) {
  ...
}
```

If I try the url http://localhost/api/values/testing, it will go into:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get (int id) {
 ...
}
```

Which is also in ValuesController.cs.

Any ideas why the first method is not triggering?

Comment: Usually you *post* when you want to send something like json.  I'm not quite sure I understand your question however.   If you attribute the methods properly, you can deserialize (using json.net) into your class object.

Comment: Why don't you just pass it as a `C#` class instead of creating a `JSON` object and then passing it to a web api that takes a c# class?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a URL that contains the properties of `MyClass` on the query string and invoke the remote client with HttpClient (or a third party option like RestSharp).

In addition, you need to mark your WebAPI endpoint method with `[FromUri]` so that it knows to expect a complex type from the query string rather than the request body.

```
[HttpGet("/")]
public string Index ([FromUri] MyClass aclass) {
    ...
}

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://.../");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var url = String.Format("api/ControllerName?ID={0}&Dept={1}", 
        myModel.ID, myModel.Dept);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        MyModel model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();
    }
}
```

In this particular case you actually don't need to create a JSON string since you can pass all of the required data on the query string.  If you don't want to expose the data, you should consider changing it to a post, at which point you can post the object directly.

```
...
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, myModel);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Json.NET by Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If you change your endpoint to accept a `Stream`, I think you can do something like this:

```
var myClass = new JsonSerializer()
                  .Deserialize<MyClass>(
                    new JsonTextReader(
                      new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1, true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to serialize and deserialize JSON into objects. [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is pretty good at doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple RestSharp client: http://restsharp.org

```
var client = new RestClient(" http://localhost/api/values");
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { Name = "Miroslav" });
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I did not catch your controller structure, but you can update this example.

Documentation: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki